# c# math function for averaged above average, without using a list is that possible?

Tags: c#, math, statistics

in general average is easy to calculate.
but how would one calculate the running upper average ?.

Imagine a school of kids where one would like to calculate the average of the kids who are above average. 
While you "run" by each grade sample of kid you add more score data of kid. 
You calculate the average and devide by the kids who've you have past by.

Such sample could look like:

```
kid     1     2     3    4      5
score   9     7     4    1      1
runav   9     8     4    5.25   3.6
```

if you want to calculate the upper average

```
upavg   -     9    8.5    8.5   !!!!
```

I placed - because after first kid there is no upper average 
I placed !!! there because after kid 5, 
The average 3.6 now makes kid 3 an above average kids
And suddenly the average of the above average kids becomes (9+8+4)/3 = 7

Inititally i wrote below class to calculate this, but then i realized that it wouldnt work for the kids example i explained earlier.

```
class QuarterUP
{
    private ulong count;
    private ulong countupper;
    private double average;
    private double averageup;
    private ulong sum;
    private ulong sumup;

    public QuarterUP()  //constructor
    {
        this.count = 0;
        this.countupper = 0;
        this.average = 0;
        this.averageup = 0;
        this.sum = 0;
        this.sumup = 0;
    }

    public ulong GetCount() { return this.countupper; }

    public ulong GetCountAll(){ return this.count; }

    public void Add(int i) // all logic is in here
    {
        this.count++;
        this.sum = this.sum + (ulong)i;
        this.average = this.sum * (1.0 / this.count);

        if (i > this.average)
        {
            this.countupper++;
            this.sumup = this.sumup + (ulong)i;
            this.averageup = this.averageup * (1.0 / this.countupper);
        }
    }

    public double Average()   // my current best answer
   {
        return this.averageup;
    }

}
```

One solution to solve this is to keep a track list of scores.
But since i have to process eventually lots of scores fast, going trough a long list will be to slow. And so i wonder if there is some math or code function possible to calculate it without such a list, as currently i consider my class to be an estimate, but not the best function there is.

Comment: It can't be done without holding onto the list.  I doubt that your list will be so long that processing time will be the issue.  Memory is more likely to kill you first.

Comment: i got about 7  miliseconds to get a result, i'm doing graphics stuff with camera's. beyond that my realtime app starts to lag. those kids in my example are actually pixel serie values.

Comment: You need to rethink what you're doing.  You might have better luck here if you describe the real problem instead of using this contrived example.

Comment: I prefer to describe my problems in ways anybody can understand them. 
That they are parts of much complexer math doesnt matter, currently i use the code above. I'm asking for specific better problem solution if possible, if there is no such math, then so be it.

Comment: None that I know.  Good luck.   My point is that you have a pre-conceived notion of how to solve this problem.  If an expert in image processing knew what you were really after they might know of a technique that would be a big improvement over your contrived kid analogy.  Your choice.

Comment: I myself  work for  several years (non stop) dedicated to image processing.
In the area of robotic vision and industrial applications :)

Comment: Good luck to you, then.  You should be all set.

Comment: thanks while driving home thought about creating a running average +   running standard deviation * factor.